# Is there a way to render Loopback 4 "/explorer" in collapsed mode by default

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I have installed Loopback 4, and mounted my legacy Loopback 3 app into it as part of my migration - all good so far.

However my (swagger-ui shaped) explorer renders expanded by default - and there are a LOT of endpoints and services - making it very hard to find what I'm looking for.

My instinct tells me I should be able to add a configuration here in my `application.ts` - but I cannot find anything.

```
    this.configure(RestExplorerBindings.COMPONENT).to({
      path: '/explorer',
      docExpansion:'none'    <<<<< this is what I would expect/like
    });
    this.component(RestExplorerComponent);
```

Has anyone been able to accomplish this?  It seems from the forums there are a lot of requests for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loopback/rest-explorer

Overriding the Swagger UI index.html
For more flexibility, the `indexTemplatePath` property can be used to allow full customization of Swagger UI configuration options.

`indexTemplatePath` should be an absolute path to a html.ejs template.

To get started, download the default [index.html.ejs](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest-explorer/templates/index.html.ejs),
add `/explorer/index.html.ejs` to your project, and update the configuration:

```
this.configure(RestExplorerBindings.COMPONENT).to({
    // For example, create a directory "explorer" at the same level
    // as "src" and "node_modules" in your applciation structure
    indexTemplatePath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../explorer/index.html.ejs'),
});
```

you can then add

```
docExpansion: 'none',
```

inside the index.html.ejs file.

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: '<%- openApiSpecUrl %>',
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    filter: true,
    docExpansion: 'none',
    defaultModelsExpandDepth: 0,
    defaultModelExpandDepth: 0,
    presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        // SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.slice(1) // Disable the top bar
    ],
    plugins: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: 'StandaloneLayout'
    })
```

Comment: ok thanks - i will check it out this evening and report back

Comment: it works perfectly - so simple when you know where to look - thank you